# How to force cmake link against custom gcc libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake

I'm trying to compile my program with **custom** gcc, after cmake generated makefiles. I've done following:

1. Compiled gcc 5.2.0 from source
2. Set cmake variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to path to custom built, let's say `/home/user/pkgs/bin/g++`.
3. Ran cmake, it completed successfully
4. Ran make, it also completed succesfully

However, when I'm trying to run program it shows erros like:
  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found`

It seems to me, that problem is in linking to old libraries in `/usr/lib`, whereas linking should be done to cutom gcc libraries.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not specific to CMake. You have it with all custom installs of GCC, that ship a new version of libstdc++.

You can either change your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to your gcc install path

```
export "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/pkgs/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

or you could link statically to libstdc++.so.6 by adding `-static-libstdc++` to your CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or you could change the rpath of your target to include `/home/user/pkgs/lib` (see [cmake wiki on rpath)](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling)
, however this only works if you run the program only on the machine it was compiled on.

Comment: But how to deal with this issue if the custom install of GCC ships an older version of libstdc++ (and you need to configure a project that must be linked with that version)? Simply changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH before CMake invocation just prevents CMake from running since it needs newer glibc.